# rails cocoon dependence on select and multiple render item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, cocoon-gem

i'm new here and learning rails.
So, in my first app successful use gem cocoon. But, i want more! :)
This are my 4 tables:

1. `LABS` ( attributes {:name)
2. `RESULTS` (belongs_to :lab, belongs_to :reference) (attributes {:value, :lab_id, :reference_id})
3. `REFERENCES` (belongs_to :category)  (attributes {:name, :value, :category_id})
4. `CATEGORY` (attributes {:name})

The relations work's great! 
From `LABS` i insert records to `RESULTS` using cocoon. When i clic in the add_link, that show fields of `RESULTS` table to complete (except lab_id).
Now, i want to display a **list of `RESULTS` fields** with the previews selection of `CATEGORY`. So, will display the quantity of items that belongs_to the `CATEGORY` selected.

My cocoon code in `LABS/_FORM.HTML.ERB` is:

```
<fieldset id="results" >
<%= f.fields_for :results do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'results_fields', :f => builder %>  
  <% end %>
  <p id="links" align="center">
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :results, { class:"btn btn-success" } %>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Please help!

Again me! :)
Well, this is my new approach:

```
<% lab_cats = Category.all %>
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <% lab_cats.each do |category| %>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#cat_<%= category.id %>_tab" aria-controls="cat_<%= category.id %>_tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%= category.name %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <% lab_cats.each do |category| %>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="cat_<%= category.id %>_tab">

    <% category.references.order(:name).each do |ref| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :results do |ff| %>
    <div class="nested-fields">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="field">
            <label class="control-label"><%=  t('reference', :default => 'Reference') %>:</label>                      
            <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="<%= ref.name %>" disabled> 
            <%= ff.hidden_field :reference_id, :value => ref.id %>   
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="field">
            <label class="control-label"><%=  t('value', :default => 'Value') %>:</label> 
            <%= ff.text_field :value, :class => 'form-control', placeholder: 'Value' %>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <% end %> 
    <% end %> 

  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<!-- END Tab panes -->
```

I add in my `lab_controller.rb` this:

```
# GET /labs/new
def new
@lab = Lab.new
@lab.results.build
end

# GET /labs/1/edit
def edit    
end
```

It work's great for `new`. But, not for `edit`.

Thank's you all!

Comment: Is the 2nd field the one called by 'results_fields'?  What file is the 2nd field if not?